# CuDNNLSTM tf.v1 layer on tensorflow v2 or training on CuDNN LSTM implementation on Colab with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to make sure my keras LSTM models are actually training on GPU on Colab (I have Colab Pro). The epoch speeds vary dramatically so I have no idea what is going on. I checked the keras docs for LSTM layers and it says you have to meet these reqs:

```
The requirements to use the cuDNN implementation are:
1. activation
 == tanh
2. recurrent_activation
 == sigmoid
3. recurrent_dropout
 == 0
4. unroll
 is False
5. use_bias
 is True
6. Inputs are not masked or strictly right padded.
```

Which are all met (they are all default anyway). However, when I change activation to 'relu' instead, the speed doesn't change. This makes no sense as I would expect the speed to decrease a lot if not using the cuDNN implemenation (i.e. slower speed with activation=relu instead of activation=tanh). Here is the model:

```
def LSTM_model_2(LSTM_units=[200,200], n_steps_in=10, num_features=6, loss=custom_loss_metric, LSTM_activation='tanh', verbose=False):
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(LSTM_units[0], activation=LSTM_activation, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, num_features)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(LSTM(LSTM_units[1], activation=LSTM_activation))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(num_features))
  # model.add(Activation("relu"))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
  # opt_LSTM = SGD(lr=0.05, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=1.0)
  opt_LSTM = Adam(lr=0.001)
  model.compile(optimizer=opt_LSTM, loss=loss)
  if verbose: 
    print(model.summary())
  return model
```

Alternatively I found that tensorflow v1 has a specific CuDNNLSTM layer. I tried to import it like this:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
```

But then my model doesn't work with this layer, because it seems like you cannot mix and match v1 and v2 stuff, here's the model:

```
def CuDNNLSTM_model(LSTM_units=[200,200], n_steps_in=10, num_features=6, loss=custom_loss_metric, verbose=False):
  model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(CuDNNLSTM(LSTM_units[0], return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps_in, num_features)))
  # model.add(tensorflow.keras.Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(CuDNNLSTM(LSTM_units[1]))
  # model.add(tensorflow.keras.Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Dense(num_features))
  # model.add(Activation("relu"))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
  # opt_LSTM = SGD(lr=0.05, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=1.0)
  # opt_LSTM = Adam(lr=0.001)
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss)
  if verbose: 
    print(model.summary())
  return model
```

If I use just `keras.Sequential()` it won't find the `CuDNNLSTM` layer, but if I use `tensorflow.keras.Sequential()` the `Dropout`, `Dense` and `LeakyReLU` layers aren't found:

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7f736a163e10>
```

Any ideas how to make sure it is running on the CuDNN implemenation?
For reference, training this model with X_train size of about 750,000 rolling windows of 10 timesteps each and y_train of same size with window of 1 timestep output takes about 1.5 hours per epoch (batch_size=10). Is this typical? Seems quite long.